# REST api want to receive the dynamic data

Tags: java, api, rest

I am a new guy to Java and to the REST API .I would like to know the way of receiving the dynamic data from client by REST api in java and process it.

**For example,**

Some times client will send the data like below,

```
     {

    "User" : "XXXX",

    "Role" : "ZZZZ",

    "Product" : 

    {
    "Name" : "yyyy",

    "Valid to" : "04/4/2025",

    "Licensed version" : "jjjjj",

    },

    }
```

In the next contract, client may send like below,

```
{

"User" : "XXXX",

"Role" : "ZZZZ",

"Product" : 

{
"Name" : "yyyy",

"Expiry Date" : "04/4/2025",

"Activation Date" : "jjjjj",

},
}
```

By referring the both examples, "Product" section having  different data .For additional information may Client can send the additional data in this "Product" section. Would it be possible to make my REST Api to receive this type of dynamic data?.

If possible please let me know how can my REST api will able to receive this type of dynamic data and process it?.

Thanks

Comment: Add a field for each possible information on your Product class. That's the way to go (and it's OK because any other info will probably not be handled)

Comment: put the response in a generic json object. then iterate over and check for keys and values present.

Comment: This is a rather broad question. You have to have some definition of the API and what JSON it can return. Then it's a matter of coding your Java to understand and handle the possibilities.  What is the question?

Comment: put all possible keys to the `Product` if particular property have some values then set the value accordingly otherwise pass `null` or default value accordingly.. this may resolve your problem..
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I do the same in php with the slim network and Doctrine 2. In Doctrine 2 i defined the entities with all the possible fields. In my javascript fronted, i collect the dynamic data and then deserialize it into the entityclasses. The classes can get saved into the database then or you can do whatever you need to do to process the data.

http://www.restapitutorial.com/ is a very good tutorial on how to design your REST API, i suggest reading it.